# https://github.com/ildoonet/tf-pose-estimation steps gives me error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

[image]

`(tfpose) C:\Code\tf-openpose>python run_webcam.py --model=mobilenet_thin --resize=432x368 --camera=0`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File`"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",` line 17, in swig_import_helper
   `return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\importlib\__init__.py",`line 12
6, in `import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError:` DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `"run.py"`, line 6, in 
    from tf_pose import common
  File `"C:\Code\tf-openpose\tf_pose\__init__.py"`, line 5, in 
    from tf_pose.runner import infer, Estimator, get_estimator
  File `"C:\Code\tf-openpose\tf_pose\runner.py"`, line 7, in 
    from tf_pose import common
  File `"C:\Code\tf-openpose\tf_pose\common.py"`, line 3, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
  File `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init
__.py"`, line 22, in 
    from `tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import`
  File `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow.py",` line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow.py"`, line 58, in 
    from `tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",` line 18, in `<module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python
\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",`line 17, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File `"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tfpose\lib\importlib\__init__.py",` line 12
6, in `import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)`
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_probl
ems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Please post stack trace as text, not as image

Comment: Can you include some code, not just the stack trace?

Comment: I followed this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUjGLjOmF7o,

Comment: Main Code - https://github.com/ildoonet/tf-pose-estimation